# Error deploying juju-gui in internal openstack environment.(ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up)

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I have installed the openstack cloud using openstack Autopilot.
I am trying to deploy juju-gui in the internal juju environment.

I did the following:

1. `export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju`
2. `juju status`
3. `` juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash' ``
4. `juju status`
5. `juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui`

gives:

> ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up

I am using juju version 1.25.3

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I updated juju to 1.25.4 praposed version. using the following guide  http://askubuntu.com/questions/743934/cant-upgrade-juju-from-1-25-3-to-1-25-4-due-to-missing-tools

Comment: But still cannot deploy juju-gui        "ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up: cannot acquire lock: open /home/ubuntu/.go-cookies.lock: permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1534643

A fix has been committed and will be released in juju 1.25.4 /

I too would like to know if there is a temporary work around as i am not sure when 1.25.4 will be released.