# Can't upgrade juju from 1.25.3 to 1.25.4 due to missing tools

Tags: upgrade, juju

I am trying to upgrade juju version from 1.25.3 to 1.25.4. but I am getting error

```
juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 no matching tools available
```

Used the repository

```
add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable to install juju.
```

---

```
$ juju version
1.25.3-trusty-amd64

$ juju upgrade-juju --version 1.25.4 --debug                                                                                                        
2016-03-09 17:26:31 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.25.3-trusty-amd64 gc]                                                                      
2016-03-09 17:26:31 DEBUG juju.api api.go:154 trying cached API connection settings - endpoints [10.1.1.151:17070]                                              
2016-03-09 17:26:31 INFO juju.api api.go:266 connecting to API addresses: [10.1.1.151:17070]                                                                    
2016-03-09 17:26:31 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:262 dialing "wss://10.1.1.151:17070/environment/f7065ef7-c5e7-4a40-8f7e-67717f0fd984/api"                        
2016-03-09 17:26:31 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:194 connection established to [10.1.1.151:17070] to [10.1.1.151:17070 node1.maas:17070] - resolving hostnames        
2016-03-09 17:26:36 DEBUG juju.network hostport.go:162 removing unresolvable address "node1.maas": lookup node1.maas: no such host                              
2016-03-09 17:26:36 DEBUG juju.api api.go:497 API addresses unchanged                                                                                           
2016-03-09 17:26:36 DEBUG juju.api api.go:506 cacheChangedAPIInfo: serverUUID="f7065ef7-c5e7-4a40-8f7e-67717f0fd984"                                            
2016-03-09 17:26:41 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 no matching tools available
```

Can you help me out resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.25.4 hasn't been released yet. Instead it's a [proposed release](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2016-March/006786.html). Proposed releases are made available for early testing and validation by users and shouldn't be used to upgrade production environments without the understanding that this may break your deployment.

As for your question, there are two different versions of Juju. There is the Juju client installed on your machine and the Juju version deployed in an environment. `juju version` will print your client version, but each environment created will have it's own version. For example you may have a staging environment and production environment. Upgrading juju for those environments is two independent actions and is what `juju upgrade-juju` command is designed to do.

So, if you want to test Juju 1.25.4 before it's release you'll need to do a few things. First, you'll need to update your environment to use the proposed stream. Juju uses streams (stable, proposed, devel) to advertise versions of Juju agents available. You created the environment with the stable stream and since 1.25.4 isn't released yet it's not in stable. If you stop now and wait for it to be released, when 1.25.4 goes to stable, `juju upgrade-juju` will work as expected. You do not have to upgrade the Juju client to upgrade an environment.

## Upgrading Juju Environment

To continue, run `juju set-environment agent-stream=proposed`. You may get a warning about the key not existing, this is OK. Once that's run, you should be able to issue `juju upgrade-juju` to get 1.25.4 - after the upgrade I recommend moving agent-stream back to `released` or simply running `juju unset-environment agent-stream` to revert back to default.

## Upgrading Juju Client

To upgrade the Juju client, simply add `ppa:juju/proposed` and do an apt update/upgrade

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/proposed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju juju-core
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marco, Really appreciate your reply.

Comment: How can i bypass the following bug ?

bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1534643 

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui 

Getting this Error "ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up"

Comment: Ah, in that case, you'll probably want to upgrade to 1.25.4 since it directly addresses this bug

Comment: How can i upgrade juju version in landscape-server/0 ?

Comment: After i upgrade to 1.25.4 still I am getting error  

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui
ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up: cannot acquire lock: open /home/ubuntu/.go-cookies.lock: permission denied.

Please let me know how can i resolve it!!